# where does Google test core web vitals from?

Tags: google, core-web-vitals

Is it possible to know where Google tests core web vitals from?

I ask so that I can prepare our Cloudflare cache for their tests.

I say this because ahrefs.com runs its site audit from France, and was reporting slow speeds.

This is because we don't get a lot of traffic from France so the Cloudflare edge in France would not have been populated, so the speed would not have been as optimised as a fully cached country where we receive regular traffic from.

Comment: CWV are based on real user experiences. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/86521401/core-web-vitals-page-experience-faqs?hl=en, specifically the Chrome UX Report (CrUX).

Comment: @RickViscomi That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Comment: True great answer